# Parallel processing of Jobs from Queues in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, queue, multiprocessing

I have just started working on a project. What I want to do after completion is:

-put X job commands on a queue  (main function)

-work on Y jobs at all times out of those X, in parallel threads. (I am thinking Semaphores)

-Be able to read the current status, kill or restart a specific job out of the currently running Y, from command line

**Now I want you to give me feedback, how would you approach this problem?**

-for working on Y jobs out of X. 
Should I be using semaphores or pool process or what else?
I also want to be able to change process Width during a process...
(I use a grid to invoke scripts. If I decrease processes it will increase my speed, some jobs(results) become high priority at times)

Comment: I think your code may be considerably simpler if you use [`multiprocessing.Pool`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)

Comment: what issue are you having? Are you just looking for feedback? Please be more explicit.

Comment: I put 100 parallel processes over night. next morning i come back and the processes are still running, now i want 3 of the 100 processes urgently.

what i want to do is to be able to kill selective processes.
in the case of multiprocessing.pool i want to be able to change the number of processes while processing. is that possible?  if not, what approach should i take ?

Comment: You have a very similar problem to [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266161/pausing-and-restarting-all-python-processes) question I believe. The resulting client application that controls all the processes would be rather involved imao, so make sure it's worth your time..